# Ways to give a process "idle" network priority

Tags: networking, priority

When I'm playing a game, I don't want Dropbox taking hogging my network connection. I have been able to noticeably reduce my latency by turning it off while playing. The same is true to a lesser extend for web browsing.

I'm looking for network equivalents for niceness and scheduling policies (`SCHED_BATCH` etc. in schedtool). Does such a thing exist? Alternatively, automatically cutting off network access for a specific process while another one is running would work too.

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is work for a [traffic shaper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_shaping), so that is what you should look for. As for identifying what packets belong to what application, you will probably want to look at [network namespaces](http://lwn.net/Articles/219794/) and/or [Cgroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups), but I would expect there to be some ready-to-use solutions (likely based on these).

Comment: I already knew about these building blocks but never used them before. A ready-made solution is what I am in fact looking for.